# Параллельное программирование в андроид

Tags: java, android, c++, распараллеливание, openmp

В андроид есть поддержка c++, значит можно на базе андроид смартфонов организовывать параллельные вычисления на OpenMP? Есть ли такая поддержка в андроид или похожие библиотеки в Java для параллельных вычислений на android?

Comment: А просто new Thread(), вас в Java не устроит?

Comment: Интерфейсы( как OpenMP) решают многие проблемы, коллизию напоимер, поэтому хотелось бы узнать есть ли подобные решения чтобы я не делать велосипеды

Comment: А что говорит гугл по поводу `OpenMP java`?

Comment: Вообще вы можете просто написать код на плюсах с помощью Android NDK и там использовать openMP

Comment: OpenMP ничего не решает. вам малейший пшик надо описывать, обычный new Thread() джавы в милилард раз удобнее и понятнее, да и к тому же есть RxJava у которой вообще нет конкурентов